# How to specify file extension when using inotifywait

Tags: monitoring, monitor, inotifywait, rclone

How do I specify file extensions to be monitored when using inotifywait ?

Given this code

```
cd "tmp"
inotifywait -me close_write --format %f . | while read file
do  rclone move "$file" …
done
```

Where to add the file extensions in the code? I tried replacing

```
--format %f .
```

with

```
--format %f *.tmp,*.tmp2
```

But still doesnt work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd tmp
inotifywait -m . -e close_write -e moved_from | # -m is --monitor, -e is --event, what you need
while read path action file; do
 if [[ "$file" =~ .*txt$ ]]; then # if suffix is '.txt'
  echo ${path}${file} ': '${action}
  rclone moveto $file remote:dir/$file
  echo 'Continue watching...'
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using "--include" for this

```
inotifywait -m -e modify "/tmp/" --include '.*\.log$' |
while read -r dir action file; do
    echo "The file '$file' modified in directory '$dir' via '$action'"
done
```

Will track if files with .log extension have been modified